# MySQL InnoDB Deadlock For 2 simple insert queries

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have a deadlock for this two insert queries:

```
insert into PlayerClub (modifiedBy, timeCreated, currentClubId, endingLevelPosition, nextClubId, account_id) values (0, '2014-12-23 15:47:11.596', 180, 4, 181, 561)

insert into PlayerClub (modifiedBy, timeCreated, currentClubId, endingLevelPosition, nextClubId, account_id) values (0, '2014-12-23 15:47:11.611', 180, 4, 181, 563)
```

Here is the InnoDB Status:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2014-12-23 15:47:11 1f4c
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 19896526, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 17988, OS thread handle 0x17bc, query id 5701353 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
insert into PlayerClub (modifiedBy, timeCreated, currentClubId, endingLevelPosition,  nextClubId, account_id) values (0, '2014-12-23 15:47:11.596', 180, 4, 181, 561)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 49735 page no 4 n bits 72 index `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` of   table `db`.`playerclub` trx id 19896526 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 19896542, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 17979, OS thread handle 0x1f4c, query id 5701360 localhost 127.0.0.1    root update
insert into PlayerClub (modifiedBy, timeCreated, currentClubId, endingLevelPosition,   nextClubId, account_id) values (0, '2014-12-23 15:47:11.611', 180, 4, 181, 563)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 49735 page no 4 n bits 72 index `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` of   table `db`.`playerclub` trx id 19896542 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 49735 page no 4 n bits 72 index `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` of    table `db`.`playerclub` trx id 19896542 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

The only foriegn key on this table is the "account_id".

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is my PlayerClub info:

```
CREATE TABLE `PlayerClub` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `modifiedBy` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentClubId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endingLevelPosition` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nextClubId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` (`account_id`),
  KEY `FK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES   `PlayerAccount` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What else did you do in each transaction before hitting the deadlock?

Comment: what if you issue commit after each insert and then try? Let  us know..

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE PlayerClub` please. This is usually related to indexes.

Answer (score 17):

## HERE ARE THE FACTS

Here are the two INSERTs

```
insert into PlayerClub (modifiedBy, timeCreated, currentClubId, endingLevelPosition, nextClubId, account_id) values (0, '2014-12-23 15:47:11.596', 180, 4, 181, 561)
insert into PlayerClub (modifiedBy, timeCreated, currentClubId, endingLevelPosition, nextClubId, account_id) values (0, '2014-12-23 15:47:11.611', 180, 4, 181, 563)
```

Here are the two lines from your `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

```
RECORD LOCKS space id 49735 page no 4 n bits 72 index `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` of   table `db`.`playerclub` trx id 19896526 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
RECORD LOCKS space id 49735 page no 4 n bits 72 index `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` of   table `db`.`playerclub` trx id 19896542 lock_mode X
```

## OBSERVATIONS

You doing an INSERT with two different account_ids: 561 and 563.

They are unique and should not have issues, right ? WRONG !!!

Due to InnoDB's Clustered Index, there can still be a deadlock. Why ?

Look back at your two INSERTs. The `PRIMARY KEY` on id in not specified. It must be auto generated. Any key other than the PRIMARY KEY (unique or non-unique) will have the PRIMARY KEY attached.

Please note the [MySQL Documentation on how a Secondary Index and a a Primary Key are intertwined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html):

> All indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes. In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for the row in the clustered index.
>
> If the primary key is long, the secondary indexes use more space, so it is advantageous to have a short primary key.

Although you are inserting account_id 561 and 563, under the hood you are insert `561-(id)` and `563-(id)` into the `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` index. The `PRIMARY KEY` becomes the bottleneck because the Secondary Index has to wait until the `id` column is auto_generated.

## RECOMMENDATION

You have a table with two candidate keys

- `PRIMARY KEY` on `id`
- `UNIQUE KEY` on `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh`

Since both are `BIGINT`, you could increase performance and have a smaller `PlayerClub` table by getting rid of `id` and still maintain uniqueness because of `UK_cagoa3q409gsukj51ltiokjoh` as well as avoiding this deadlock situation.

Comment: Only after removing The only foriegn key on this table is the "account_id" the deadlock stop occurring.